# Ignoring a particular attribute of a specific Node while comparing xml files using XMLUnit 2.X

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have two XML files:

```xml
<!------------------------File1--------------------------------->
    <note id="ignoreThisAttribute_1">
      <to>Experts</to>
      <from>Matrix</from>
      <heading id="dontIgnoreThisAttribute_1">Reminder</heading>
      <body>Help me with this problem</body>
    </note>
```

```xml
<!------------------------File2--------------------------------->
    <note id="ignoreThisAttribute_2">
      <to>Experts</to>
      <from>Matrix</from>
      <heading id="dontIgnoreThisAttribute_2">Reminder</heading>
      <body>Help me with this problem</body>
    </note>
```

I have to ignore the attribute:`id` of Node:`note` while comparing these two files.

I am using `DiffBuilder`:

```
Diff documentDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(srcFile).withTest(destFile).build()
```

Most online solutions suggested implementing `DifferenceEvaluator`:

Tried that as well, but this ignores all nodes with attribute id, whereas I want to ignore an attribute from a specific node:

```java
public class IgnoreAttributeDifferenceEvaluator implements DifferenceEvaluator {
        private String attributeName;
        public IgnoreAttributeDifferenceEvaluator(String attributeName) {
            this.attributeName = attributeName;
        }

        @Override
        public ComparisonResult evaluate(Comparison comparison, ComparisonResult outcome) {
            if (outcome == ComparisonResult.EQUAL)
                return outcome;
            final Node controlNode = comparison.getControlDetails().getTarget();


            System.out.println(controlNode.getNodeName());
            if (controlNode instanceof Attr) {
                Attr attr = (Attr) controlNode;
                if (attr.getName().equals(attributeName)) {
                    return ComparisonResult.EQUAL;
                }
            }
            return outcome;
        }
    }
```

Calling method in my Test class:

```java
final Diff documentDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(src).withTest(dest)
.withDifferenceEvaluator(new IgnoreAttributeDifferenceEvaluator("id"))
.build();
```

Can someone suggest me a way I can achieve this using XMLUnit 2.x
New to XMLUnit so please help accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `DifferenceEvaluator` if you really wanted to. All you'd have to do was testing the name of the `Attr`'s "owner element"'s name in addition to the name of the attribute itself.

But XMLUnit 2.x offers a different solution to this: `AttributeFilter`. The code won't be that different from the `DifferenceEvaluator` you've already got, but you won't be mixing concerns.

```
class IgnoreNoteId implements Predicate<Attr> {

    public boolean test(Attr attr) {
        return !("note".equals(attr.getOwnerElement().getNodeName())
            && "id".equals(attr.getNodeName()));
    }
}
```

or even shorter with a lambda in `withAttributeFilter` when using Java8.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. This was helpful. I used  "withAttributeFilter".
Guess I need to update my concepts of lamba (Java 8).